# Content is not wrapped in bot window

Tags: botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I'm using adaptive card to show an content to user in node js.

My Adaptive card format:

```
 "type": "TextBlock",
"text": 'Hi ' + conversationId + '!\n\n I’m Max I am new & still learning, but happy to help as best as I can!\n\nPlease select subject which you are interested in or type your question.',
"size": "medium",
"wrap": true,
"weight": "default",
"color": "green"  ,
"isSubtle": false          }       ]
```

I'm not able to see the content 
inside the bot window.
Is there a way i can wrap the content inside the bot window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBkED.png)

Comment: The image should be included in the post

Comment: this is in webchat only?  does it render correctly in other channels? Have you made any custom changes to botchat?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the card as you set it up should be fine. However the card popping out of the container as you are seeing is likely related to the width of the card in the webchat interface itself. I suggest adding a css override to your botchat css (if you are making your own version of webchat from scratch) or to your website's css in order to customize the webchat's adaptive cards. In this case something like the following should be what you want:

```
.wc-adaptive-card{
    width:200px;
}
```

Adjust the value of the width as necessary.